# Pandas - Reading in json, boolean is typed as float if it contains null value

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON file on S3 with the following data:

```
{"id": "1", "col1": null, "col2": "Test1", "col3": true}
{"id": "2", "col1": "abc", "col2": "Test2", "col3": null}
{"id": "3", "col1": "def", "col2": "Test3", "col3": true}
```

Note, col3 has boolean values in it, but one line has a null value.  Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
source_path = 's3://bucket/prefix/file.json'
df = pd.read_json(source_path, lines=True)
df.dtypes
```

Output:

```
id        int64
col1     object
col2     object
col3    float64
dtype: object
```

df:

```
    id  col1    col2    col3
0   1   None    Test1   1.0
1   2   abc     Test2   NaN
2   3   def     Test3   1.0
```

Why is it that the col3 is typed as a float?

Col1 has a null but seems to correctly be typed as an object (string).  Is there a generic way (not explicitly casting "col3" to boolean) to get the boolean type on the dataframe?

Comment: Boolean values are only true/false

Comment: In panda column will only have one type in your case is float since NaN is float

Comment: It needs to cast to a nullable dtype, hence the float64. In recent versions you can cast to a nullabe integer type such as "Int64".

Comment: @jarretg -  Do you consider `null` as `false`? If the answer is Yes - the answer below may work for you.

Comment: @balderman - This is data from a 3rd party, so I can't really say. I guess I had 2 questions, the "why is this a float type", which seems to be because Pandas doesn't allow a nullable boolean, so the null forces it to be a float. The 2nd question, "is there a generic way to get Pandas to read nulls in that column as a boolean", I think your answer means that it isn't possible. I was looking for a solution where I would **not** have to directly supply the column names.

Comment: you can read the data using boto3, modify it based on my answer  and pass it to pandas.

Answer (score 1):

For this situation, it seems that adding "dtype=False" to the read_json call gave me the desired behavior.

```
import pandas as pd
source_path = 's3://bucket/prefix/file.json'
df = pd.read_json(source_path, lines=True, dtype=False)
df.dtypes
```

Output:

```
id      object
col1    object
col2    object
col3    object
dtype: object
```

If I then write this dataframe to S3 as a parquet file, the output file is correctly typed as boolean.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** OP consider `null` as `false` we can replace the `None` values of `col3` with `False`

```
import json

data_str = '''{"id": "2", "col1": "abc", "col2": "Test2", "col3": null}'''
data = json.loads(data_str)
if not isinstance(data['col3'], bool):
    data['col3'] = False
print(data)
```